# Check if tinyMCE has a content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tinymce

I'm trying to see if my tinyMCE has a content while writing and i set a flag if yes or not (I'm using AngularJS). So this is the code i use for the tiny:

```
$scope.tinyHasContent = false;
tinymce.init({
                selector: "#elm1",
                height: 400,
                language:'it',
                plugins: [
                    "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
                    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                    "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
                ],
                content_css: "css/partials/content.css",
                toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage",
                style_formats: [
                    {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
                    {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                    {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                    {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
                    {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
                    {title: 'Table styles'},
                    {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
                ],
                setup : function(ed){
                    ed.on('NodeChange', function(e){

                        if(ed.getContent() != '' || ed.getContent() != undefined || ed.getContent() != null) {
                            $scope.tinyHasContent = true;
                            console.log('the content ' + ed.getContent() + " " + $scope.tinyHasContent);
                        } else {
                            $scope.tinyHasContent = false;
                            console.log('the content ' + ed.getContent() + " " + $scope.tinyHasContent);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Simply, while typing i can see the log what i'm writing. But the problem is that seems that there is always a content even on init because it returns always $scope.tinyHasContent = true in the log. How is possible?

By the way, summary, this is what i should do:

```
<div ng-if="tinyHasContent == false">
 <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

but actually it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Thing is `ed.getContent()` returns - even if you have not typed in anything - the default root block element (i.e. a paragraph). That's the reason why `tinyHasContent` will be true always.

To verify this you may want to print `ed.getContent()` to your console.